# could not find driver

Tags: php, pdo

У меня нету `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` в `php.ini`. Версия php у меня 7.3.1. Запускаю локалку на 4000 порту (если это важно).

Comment: От нас вы чего ждёте?

Comment: Как решить проблему

Comment: Нужно установить расширение php_pdo_mysql